# Transpose xml rows to column using xpath

Tags: c#, sql, .net, xml, xpath

I have SQL table with one column as xml-datatype. Below is how i store the xml in that xml data type field (sample two row is given below)

```
<Root>
  <Element Week="201701">
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
  </Element>
  <Element Week="201702">
        <Quantity>20</Quantity>
  </Element>
  <Element Week="201703">
        <Quantity>30</Quantity>
  </Element>
  <Element Week="201704">
        <Quantity>40</Quantity>
  </Element>
  <Element Week="201705">
        <Quantity>50</Quantity>
  </Element>
</Root>

<Root>
  <Element Week="201701">
        <Quantity>60</Quantity>
  </Element>
  <Element Week="201702">
        <Quantity>70</Quantity>
  </Element>
  <Element Week="201703">
        <Quantity>80</Quantity>
  </Element>
  <Element Week="201704">
        <Quantity>90</Quantity>
  </Element>
  <Element Week="201705">
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
  </Element>
</Root>
```

**Note: There are millions of rows. each row has one field with this xml**

Now, when i read (only two rows) from

```
PDI PNO PCO PCT NKT MKI DEL Root
A1C 13D A1  W2  0C1 A10 22A <Root><ElementWeek="201701"> <Quantity>10</Quantity></Element><ElementWeek="201702"> <Quantity>20</Quantity></Element><ElementWeek="201703"> <Quantity>30</Quantity></Element><ElementWeek="201704"> <Quantity>40</Quantity></Element><ElementWeek="201705"> <Quantity>50</Quantity></Element></Root>
A2C 14D Z1  W2  061 A10 22A <Root><ElementWeek="201701"> <Quantity>60</Quantity></Element><ElementWeek="201702"> <Quantity>70</Quantity></Element><ElementWeek="201703"> <Quantity>80</Quantity></Element><ElementWeek="201704"> <Quantity>90</Quantity></Element><ElementWeek="201705"> <Quantity>100</Quantity></Element></Root>
```

I wanted to extract the xml field and below is my expected result. With this, i will bind the data to PF grid much faster compared to JSON way of storing and looping for every element to bind

Expected Result: My Element node should be column header and text node should be the data for the element node. Also how would be the performance?

```
PDI PNO PCO PCT NKT MKI DEL 201701  201702  201703  201704  201705
A1C 13D A1  W2  0C1 A10 22A   10      20      30      40      50
A2C 14D Z1  W2  061 A10 22A   60      70      80      90      100
```

Comment: What flavor of SQL is this? SQL Server, no?

Comment: Are the values `201701` to `201705` fix or are these just examples? This looks like *year-month*... Do you need a generic approach?

Comment: Hello har07: Right now we are useing SQL Express 2016 edition for tryingbefore licenced version

Comment: Hello Shnugo: You are right i should have mentioned it. They are year and week columns (52 weeks in a year and maximum 2 to 3 years data will be stored along withe corresponding week quantity). They are completely dynamic columns. Since eveery next week the previous week is removed from master table. Also user must be able to select the week columns in custom way. For ex, user can select 201701 201710 and 201750 only three. then only three columns must be dynamically appear in column with its corresponding quantity.

Comment: You want a pivot table.  To help a need a small portion of the xml file with the header columns PDI, PNO,PCO,PCT,NKT,MKI, and DEL

Comment: Do you really want to search through *millions of rows*, looking into each row (RBAR) and use an `XQuery` against an XML column. All this as dynamically defined `PIVOT` or *grouped aggregate*. This will not work fast enough...

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML method [`value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) passing XPath/XQuery expression that will return one target element at a time, for example :

```
SELECT 
    t.MyXmlColumn.value('(/Root/Element[@Week="201701"]/Quantity)[1]', 'int') AS 201701,
    t.MyXmlColumn.value('(/Root/Element[@Week="201702"]/Quantity)[1]', 'int') AS 201702,
    ....
FROM MyTable t
```

Comment: Hi har07: thanks for the reply. One thing though, the solution looks towards nvarchar type data type. isn't it? actually our data type is xml. can you please let us know your inputs